# MongoDb query on array element

Tags: mongodb

Suppose i have a document as

```
[
    { fruits: ["apple", "orange", "banana", "watermelon", "grapes"] },
    { fruits: ["watermelon", "banana"] },
    { fruits: ["pineapples", "apple", "orange", "banana"] },
    { fruits: ["apple", "orange"] },
    { fruits: ["banana"] },
    { fruits: ["apple", "orange", "banana"] }
]
```

Now i want to find a document where it should have **apple** and **orange** and other fruits as optional.I mean
if i search
for `"apple","orange","banana"` in that
case it should give me document which must have **apple** and **orange** and **banana** as optional

for example it should give me result as

```
[ 
    {  fruits: ["apple", "orange", "banana"] },
    { fruits: ["apple", "orange"] },
]
```

As you can see above it should only give me document that contains **apple** and **orange** and **banana** as optional

Comment: your document is not valid. please make sure you build it correctly

Comment: Sorry my structure was not proper it was hard coded  just for explanation not actual document from my db

Comment: You can try `db.getCollection('fruite').find({fruits: { $in: ["apple",'orange'] } })`

Comment: You need this `{ fruits: ["apple", "orange", "banana", "watermelon", "grapes"] },` in output?

Comment: @IftekharDani this will return me all document which have apple and orange. I don't want this. I want document which must have apple and orange and it may or may not have banana. and not other fruits in document

Comment: @IftekharDani no read my question i have mentioned what result i want

Comment: This might be help `db.getCollection('fruite').find({ $or: [ { fruits:  ["apple",'orange']  }, {  fruits: ["apple",'orange', 'banana']  } ] } )`

Comment: Your second object doesn't contain `banana` here `{ fruits: ["apple", "orange"] }` ???

Answer (score 0):

update:

not sure this is the exact query i would use in production code but it works:

```
db.getCollection('yourCollection').find({ $or : [
    {"fruits": ["apple","orange"]},
    {"fruits": ["apple","orange","banana"]}
]})
```

Comment: this will not give me desired result. Please look into my question i have mentioned what result i want

Comment: see the new query